# Simplify switch expression that updates private member

Tags: java, switch-statement, mapping

I want to simplify this logic:

```
  private String member_A;
  private String member_B;
  private String member_C;
  private String member_D;

 private void xyz(Object x, String s) {
 switch (s) {
    case "A":
      member_A = x.getInternalNumber();
      break;
    case "B":
      member_B = x.getInternalNumber();
      break;
    case "C":
      member_C = x.getInternalNumber();
      break;
    case "D":
      member_D = x.getInternalNumber();
      break;
    default:
    }
 }


 xyz(x, "A");
 ...
 xyz(x, "B");
 ...
 etc
```

The `switch` shall be replaced by a more elegant solution. Technically, the calls of xyz(...) shall update the correct field with some value. 
Does anyone has an idea to improve this?

Comment: What about storing the `member_X`s in a `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: yep, tried, but is the string member really changeable?

Comment: Just call `put` to change the value. What's the problem?

Comment: Why not just call `member_A = x.getInternalNumber();` (etc) directly?

Comment: Thanks! Map + .put() lead me to the right decision.

Answer (score 0):

If your naming conventions of your member variables is as given in your example code, you can use reflection. If it's more elegant than what you have right now, that's debatable.

```
private void xyz(Object x, String s) {
    try {
        Field member = YourClass.class.getDeclaredField("member_"+s); //replace YourClass with your class name
        member.setAccessible(true);
        member.set(this, x.getInternalNumber());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException ex) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `class` Member. Maybe something like this:

```
class Member {

    String string;
    char member;

    Member (char member) {
        this.string = null;
        this.member = member;
    }
}
```

Then make an `array` of members, then test each one in a `foreach` loop, like this:

```
private void test(char s) {
    for (Member m : members) {
        if (m.member == s) {
            m.string = "Whatever you want that member string to be equal to";
        }
    }
}
```